# Interpretation of impulse response functions with variables in logs

Tags: interpretation, logarithm, vector-error-correction-model, impulse-response

I am looking at the relationship of several macroeconomic variables, all in natural logs, using Vector Error Correction (VECM) models and Impulse Response Functions with a standard Cholesky-type ordering. I understand that the long-run cointegrating equations (the error correction terms) contained within the VEC can be interpreted in percentage terms when all variables are in logs, e.g. log(X), log(Y), ...: "A y% change in variable Y is associated with a x% change in variable X". But I was wondering how one would interpret the final impulse response functions of such a model, especially in terms of units, relative size and persistence?

Would it be as simple as interpreting the responses as "a change of x% in response to a 1% shock" and cumulating the x% over time?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your "A y% change in variable Y is associated with a x% change in variable X" regarding the long run equation. _Lutkepohl (1994) Interpretation of Cointegating Relations, econometric reviews, 13, 391-394_ discusses the problems associated with interpreting the coefficients of the cointegrating relations as elasticities.